# Capture logs from Chrome during test is running. Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to capture logs from chrome, during automated test is running. Code is below:

```
 binary_path = 'Chromium'
chromedriver_path = 'chromedriver'

opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = binary_path
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL',
                           'driver': 'ALL'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, desired_capabilities=d, options=opts)

#EXAMPLE TO GET LOGS
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('abc')

print('browser = ', driver.get_log('browser'))
print('driver = ', driver.get_log('driver'))
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print('entry = ', entry)

driver.quit()
```

output from print:

```
browser =  []
driver =  []
```

My question is, why entry isn't printing and why there is no output from chrome logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [ChromeOptions](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) instead of Options.

Also, not sure why you use Chromium, this might affect the result. 
I modified your code and following code worked for me with Chrome browser:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

opts = ChromeOptions()
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL',
                           'driver': 'ALL'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=d, options=opts)

#EXAMPLE TO GET LOGS
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('abc')

print('browser = ', driver.get_log('browser'))
print('driver = ', driver.get_log('driver'))
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print('entry = ', entry)

driver.quit()
```

it printed out =>

```
browser =  []
driver =  [{'level': 'INFO', 'message': 'Populating Preferences file: {\n   "alternate_error_pages": {\n      "enabled": false\n   },\n   "autofill": {\n      "enabled": false\n   }, ... ]
```

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: When i remove chromium, selenium throw exception: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64)` and still have empty list brackets. What version of chromedriver are you using?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. `ChromeOptions` are needed and also path to chromium. When i'm using `d['goog:loggingPrefs']` there is no logs, when i'm using `d['loggingPrefs']` everything works fine

Comment: Great, glad you found it! Yeah, I didn’t try Chromium.

Comment: According to selenium.webdriver.__init__.py it seems that `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options` and `selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions` are the same:  `from .chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions`